# on my flutter project using Audie Generator for injection the project can't compile without the files generated by the test integration

Tags: flutter-test

Because every version of audie_generator from path depends on analyzer >=0.33.3 <0.36.0 and test >=1.6.7 <1.9.3 depends on analyzer >=0.36.0 <0.39.0, audie_generator from path is incompatible with test >=1.6.7 <1.9.3